# How to sort tuple according to list value?

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I have a with this structure:

```
players={ 'Player one': [3, 0], 'Player two': [13, 1], 'Player three': [29, 0], 'Player four': [19, 5] }
```

The first number of the list is the number of games and the next is the number of goals.

To sort the array by the number of games I just use:

```
print sorted(players.items(), key=lambda kv:(kv[1], kv[0]),reverse=True)
```

This works great but I found no way to sort by the number of goals (the second number of the list).
What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply specify searching through the second index:

```
players={ 'Player one': [3, 0], 'Player two': [13, 1], 'Player three': [29, 0], 'Player four': [19, 5] }

sorted(players.items(), key=lambda kv:(kv[1][1], kv[0]),reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort exclusively by the second number of the list with this:

```
sorted(players.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1][1], reverse=True)
```

Where `lambda kv: kv[1][1]` basically extracts the second `[1]` value of each list `kv[1]`

Comment: Doing this disregards sorting based on the first element of the list

Comment: @alec_a the OP's question can be interpretable, but since he mentioned Quote: ***I found no way to sort by the number of goals***, I assumed that he wanted to sort only by that `kv[1][1]`